# Change app opening animation

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there any way to change / disable that animation when an app is opening (e.g. slide up animation in Lolipop).

I have tried this, but without success:

```
<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom animation. Using basics of themes in android it can be done. Below just delete any line you don't want to define your own animation for and it will fall back to the default android animation.

```
<!-- this goes in your theme -->
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyActivityAnimations</item>

<!-- Standard animations for a full-screen window or activity. -->
<style name="MyActivityAnimations" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_open_enter</item>
    <item name="activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/activity_open_exit</item>
    <item name="activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_close_enter</item>
    <item name="activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/activity_close_exit</item>
    <item name="taskOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/task_open_enter</item>
    <item name="taskOpenExitAnimation">@anim/task_open_exit</item>
    <item name="taskCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/task_close_enter</item>
    <item name="taskCloseExitAnimation">@anim/task_close_exit</item>
    <item name="taskToFrontEnterAnimation">@anim/task_open_enter</item>
    <item name="taskToFrontExitAnimation">@anim/task_open_exit</item>
    <item name="taskToBackEnterAnimation">@anim/task_close_enter</item>
    <item name="taskToBackExitAnimation">@anim/task_close_exit</item>
    <item name="wallpaperOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_open_enter</item>
    <item name="wallpaperOpenExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_open_exit</item>
    <item name="wallpaperCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_close_enter</item>
    <item name="wallpaperCloseExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_close_exit</item>
    <item name="wallpaperIntraOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_open_enter</item>
    <item name="wallpaperIntraOpenExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_open_exit</item>
    <item name="wallpaperIntraCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_close_enter</item>
    <item name="wallpaperIntraCloseExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_close_exit</item>
</style>
```